# Alert in Sybase ASE version 11

Tags: alert, sybase, snmp, sap-ase

Is it possible to get alert's in Sybase ASE version 11. I'm looking for alert's in terms of any table changes and DB space. Can it generate SNMP traps. Kindly please point me to a document that can help me.

Comment: That version of Sybase is almost 20 years old.  You might be able to find some docs related to 11.9.2, but anything older than that is going to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael mentioned, this is a really old version of ASE. However, you wouldn't be the first person to inherit a less-than-current system...

I have seen alerts triggered by ASE by calling xp_cmdshell and executing a script on the server, passing details of the alert. The choice of scripting language and type of alert is up to you, but you could have the script send an email with the recipients and message passed to it as parameters.

Documentation for xp_cmdshell and other extended stored procedures is here:
[Sydney Extended Stored Procedures](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1600/doc/html/san1393052115747.html). While this is for the current version of ASE, nothing looks like it has changed since v11 (from a quick look only)

Note that if you are running on Windows you also have access to xp_sendmail which may be simpler to use.

You'll have to get inventive if you want to check for changed tables, etc. but I suppose it is possible. Having said that, I wouldn't be investing the time on such an old DB myself.

Comment: Thank you John, it's a good lead. We need to survive with this DB for quite some time, hence we need alert's on certain things. I'm currently reading about xp_cmdshell. Do you have good links that you could share regarding xp_cmdshell. Also I was trying C# to hook up to the DB (ASE 11). I got the SAP ASE 16 SDK, but couldn't get the ODBC to work. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I've added the link to the Sybase doco to my answer. Beyond that I don't have any links. Also check out xp_sendmail if you are running on Windows instead of unix. Regarding ODBC, you will get more responses if you post a separate question for this.